# Error "Does not contain a static "Main" Method suitable for an entry point

Tags: c#, codedom

I got this Error when I try to compile a sourcecode with CodeDom

> Does not contain a static "Main" Method suitable for an entry point!

I already googled it and read other answers here, but I dont know how to fix it.

Can someone please help me?
Here is my source code : 
http://picz.to/image/ao5n

```
    ^        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog d = new SaveFileDialog();
        d.Filter = "Executable (*.exe)|*.exe";
        if (d.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string source = Properties.Resources.source;
            CompilerParameters param = new CompilerParameters();
            param.CompilerOptions += "/target:winexe" + " " + "/win32icon:" + "\"" + textBox1.Text + "\"";
            param.GenerateExecutable = true;
            param.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");
            param.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
            param.OutputAssembly = d.FileName;

            StringBuilder Temp = new StringBuilder();
            String InputCode = String.Empty;
            InputCode = "MessageBox.Show((1 + 2 + 3).ToString());";
            Temp.AppendLine(@"using System;");
            Temp.AppendLine(@"using System.Windows.Forms;");
            Temp.AppendLine(@"namespace RunTimeCompiler{");
            Temp.AppendLine(@"static void Main(string[] args){");

            Temp.AppendLine(@"public class Test{");
            Temp.AppendLine(@"public void Ergebnis(){");

            Temp.AppendLine(InputCode);
            Temp.AppendLine(@"}}}}");
            CompilerResults result = new CSharpCodeProvider().CompileAssemblyFromSource(param, Temp.ToString());
            if (result.Errors.Count > 0) foreach (CompilerError err in result.Errors) MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
            else MessageBox.Show("Done.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Comment: Hint: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3 (Search Google for `C# main`)

Comment: Can you post that code in your question?

Comment: @SLaks i understand the error, but I dont know how to fix it. I already tried adding an static method called main into the source code, but it wont work because then I get a new Error...

Comment: it's definitely not funny, but it's a little funny

Comment: @GumGun: Methods must be defined inside of classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All C# programs need to contain the Main() method.  Essentially this is where the program starts.  The code you posted is just a small part of the entire application.  You must have removed the location where main had been residing.

[MSDN Article on Main](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228506%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Updated for comments:

A new Windows Form App has a Program class that instantiates the form that you want.

```
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
     }
```

Try copying that over to a new file called program.cs.  Make sure that Form1 now points to the form you created in the applications.

Comment: Sir I overworked my code now, but i get more errors... Please take a look at my source code again , I edited it^^

Comment: I assume this is a WinForms app?

Comment: The Errors I get are this here : http://picz.to/image/s80

Comment: No the code which should compile is just an messagebox^^

Answer (score 1):

Paste this into your class -- if you still get an error, you need to paste the entire class in question, not just a screen capture of the event handler for a button click.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  //do nothing
}
```

Comment: //do nothing should start your form though

Comment: Now i get another error : http://picz.to/image/s80 I already edited this line in, you can see it above in my post^^

Comment: I just want to compile an message box :)

Answer (score 1):

The code you've posted is the click event for a button.  A button is usually on a form, and the form must be initialized.  If you create a Windows Forms Application it will create a file Program.cs that contains a Main method that starts your form.

When you start a program, the computer needs to know where to actually start running code, that's what the Main() method is for.  It is required to run, and that's the error you are receiving.